# Apex- no viable alternative at character ' ' while substring

Tags: string, error-handling, salesforce, apex, substring

I am trying to get substring fom a string. I have a xml response and I want to get only few tags and there values to parse.
but I am getting error :- no viable alternative at character ' '

```
 responseObj.xmlResponse = response.getBody();
            String xmlbody =response.getBody();


   order OrderID=new order();
                String substr=xmlbody.substring(xmlbody.indexOf("<OrderID>"));
```

Comment: change this xmlbody.indexOf("<OrderID>")' to 'xmlbody.indexOf('<OrderID>')'

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String substr=xmlbody.substring(xmlbody.indexOf('<OrderID>'));
```